# split an table(or list) based on column python

Tags: python, sorting

I have a array

```
arr = [['a', 'b', 'a'], [1, 2, 3]
```

I need this to be spliited based on the first array values i.e based on 'a' or 'b'. So Expected output is

```
arr_out_a = [1, 3]
arr_out_b = [2]
```

How do I do it?

Please help me correct the question,if the way I'm using words like list and array might create confusion

Comment: First try to edit your question so that it's more clear what you need help with.
Second, show us what you already have attempted.

Answer (score 4):

Use `collections.defaultdict()`:

```
In [82]: arr = [['a', 'b', 'a'], [1, 2, 3]]

In [83]: from collections import defaultdict

In [84]: d = defaultdict(list)

In [85]: for i, j in zip(*arr):
   ....:     d[i].append(j)
   ....:     

In [86]: d
Out[86]: defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'b': [2], 'a': [1, 3]})
```

Comment: if the array is arr = [['x', 'y', 'z'], ['a', 'b', 'a'], [1, 2, 3]], How would I split based on the 'a', or 'b'. Expected output is arr_out_a = [['x', 1], ['z', 3] and arr_out_b = [['y', 2]

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. if the array is arr = [['x', 'y', 'z'], ['a', 'b', 'a'], [1, 2, 3]], How would I split based on the 'a', or 'b'. Expected output is arr_out_a = [['x', 1], ['z', 3] and arr_out_b = [['y', 2]. Please help the general way as the first answer, in my program I would like to split based on some string instead of a and b, and number of such strings are unknown (i.e to be determined by the arra

Comment: Hi I could try this and get answer.

import operator

arr = [['x', 'y', 'z'],  ['a', 'b', 'a'], [1, 2, 3]]
from collections import defaultdict
 
d = defaultdict(list)
 
for i, j, k in zip(*arr):
    d[j].append([i,k]) 
 
print d

Result:
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'a': [['x', 1], ['z', 3]], 'b': [['y', 2]]})

Answer (score 0):

Basically just append them conditionally to predefined empty lists:

```
arr_out_a = []
arr_out_b = []
for char, num in zip(*arr):
    if char == 'a':
        arr_out_a.append(num)
    else:
        arr_out_b.append(num)
```

or if you don't like the `zip`:

```
arr_out_a = []
arr_out_b = []
for idx in range(len(arr[0])):
    if arr[0][idx] == 'a':
        arr_out_a.append(arr[1][idx])
    else:
        arr_out_b.append(arr[1][idx])
```